# Which properties characterize the general notion of "deducibility"?

Tags: logic, soft-question

In a comment on the question, [Generalizing Henkin proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2447716/11867), [Noah Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28111/noah-schweber) referenced the article, "[An Abstract Setting for Henkin Proofs](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00136118.pdf)". In that article, the author considers a general setting in which we have a formal language that contains a constant false sentence $\bot$ and a negation connective $\neg$. We then consider a class of formulas $F$ in the language that is closed under negation and has $\bot \in F$. The author then defines a *deducibility relation* to be a relation $\vdash$ from $2^F$ to $F$ that satisfies the following:

- if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$, then $\Delta \vdash \varphi$.
- if $\varphi \in \Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$,
- if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $\Gamma, \varphi \vdash \bot$, then $\Gamma \vdash \bot$, and
- $\Gamma, \neg \varphi \vdash \bot$ if and only if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

My question is this. Why are these the "right" conditions to characterize a so-called "deducibility relation"? Is there an intuitive or heuristic (metamathematical) argument to justify isolating these particular properties as the ones which characterize deducibility? Is this notion of a general deducibility relation applicable beyond the cited paper? Or is it just an ad hoc definition based on the conditions that were needed to generalize Henkin proofs?

Comment: First two are quite obvious. The third one is a sort of consistency.

Comment: The last one is characteristic of classical logic: thus, not so common to all logics.

Comment: We need also a general form of transitiva.

Comment: See [Lindström's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem) and Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum & Wolfgang Thomas, [Mathematical Logic (Springer, 3rd ed, 2021)](https://books.google.ba/books?id=V3wwEAAAQBAJ), **Ch.XIII**, page 273.

Comment: See also [Logics as consequence relations](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/#LogiConsRela).

Comment: "Is there an intuitive argument to justify isolating these particular properties as the ones which characterize deducibility?" Maybe not - as long as each defining property is intuitively true of any "reasonable" deducibility relation, the resulting theorems apply where we expect them to.